# android handwriting to text

Tags: android, handwriting-recognition

I need to use handwriting recognition for a android app which will be used as product. Handwriting option should be as “alternative keyboard”

MyScript Stylus Mobile does provide any sdk for development?

which is best way to implement?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use gestures this will show you how to use gestures
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGestures/article.html